# Swift: как воспроизвести видеопоток?

Tags: ios, swift, mjpg

Имеется видеопоток [такого вида](http://video.ellco.ru/video12.mjpg?user=c2l0ZTIvc2l0ZTI6MDE5MjAyM2E3YmJkNzM%3D&fps=25)

Нужно воспроизвести его в стандартном плеере `iOS (AVPlayerViewController)`, как это можно сделать? Стандартный AVPlayer не хочет его воспроизводить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для воспроизведения MJPEG можно использовать эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/WrathChaos/MJPEGStreamLib) (но это все же полностью мою проблему не решает, но элементы плеера можно дорисовать и самостоятельно), однако проблему решили по другому - наш админ просто поставил другой сервер, который стримит в HLS формате, а с его произведением уже никаких проблем не оказалось.